# sequelizejs, use RegEx to query

Tags: javascript, sql, mongoose, sequelize.js

I want do something, like what I can do in Mongoose:

```
Customers.find({
            $or: [
                {firstName: {$in: RegExpArray}},
                {lastName: {$in: RegExpArray}},
                {email: {$in: RegExpArray}}
            ]
        }).limit(50);
```

I tried:

```
Customers.findAll({
            where: {
                $or: [
                    {firstName: {$iLike: {$in: RegExpArray}}},
                    {lastName: {$iLike: {$in: RegExpArray}}},
                    {email: {$iLike: {$in: RegExpArray}}}
                ]
            },
            limit: 50});
```

Also I tried use `$regex` instead of `$iLike`, or pass array `[ '%someString%', '%someString%', '%someString%'...]` instead of `RegExpArray` what should work, but non of this worked. Is it any way to use regex in query?

Comment: Can you give me a example of how the sql query would look like?

Comment: actually I can't. I'm new in SQL, always have been working with noSQL, where you can easily use regex in query like in first example.

Comment: inside your sequelize config where you have your database info add `logging: true`. That should print the sql statements that are being run.

Comment: forgot to mention. post us the sql statements that are being run use https://gist.github.com to avoid the clutter in comments.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sarkistlt/e601967bc16edd13bc5e7891493bbd5d

But in line (IN('somestring', 'alsoSomeString')) instead of ('somestring', 'alsoSomeString') should be regex statement.

Comment: Can you show me the regular expression? Hopefully we can translate that into a `LIKE` statement instead. Out of the box sql supports a `LIKE` attribute which is similar to a regex.

Comment: this is how it should work with iLike, but have no idea why it doesn't) https://gist.github.com/sarkistlt/e601967bc16edd13bc5e7891493bbd5d

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124838/discussion-between-user3254198-and-sarkis-arutiunian).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
let searchFor = [ '%someString%', '%someString%', '%someString%'...]

// basically turning the items into objects with "$iLike" as the key
searchFor = searchFor.map((item) => {
    return {$iLike: item};
});

Customer.findAll({
            where: {
                $or: [
                    {firstName: {$or: searchFor}},
                    {lastName: {$or: searchFor}},
                    {email: {$or: searchFor}}
                ]
            },
            order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
            limit: 50
        })
```

Comment: this time at least it query something) in logs I can see:
https://gist.github.com/sarkistlt/e601967bc16edd13bc5e7891493bbd5d

But still doesn't return anything

Comment: finally! Have no idea why, but if I change ```$iLike``` to ```$like``` it works, and it ignore case as it should does  ```$iLike```